# ubuntu 18.04 typing the 'd' key prints '\d' instead

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, printing

up until today, I didn't have that problem. I started my computer but everytime I try to write 'd' '\d' shows up instead. Using a 'D' shows '|D' . I tried to restart with no results. can anybody help me please? I am trying to work but even writing this question is a hell because I either have to write without 'd' or go \delete every '\' in the text.

Please help me